# Why do questions with a lot of upvotes become closed?

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-close

I posted a question once on Stack Overflow, which accumulated 25 upvotes. It has over 15,000 views, and the accepted answer has 32 upvotes.

I think my question was great, but it was **closed as too broad** by 3 people. Why?

I asked a question that comes into mind at least once in every web developers mind, and there was no duplicates either. I don't really understand why it was closed. I think it was a great question, and it was no broad at all.

You can check it out here:

[Difference between jQuery vs. AngularJS vs. Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41234070/difference-between-jquery-vs-angularjs-vs-node-js)

Comment: **5 ­­­people**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question was closed as too broad by **5 people**, not 3. The reason for that is because you asked multiple distinct questions, which each have long answers:

1. "Then what is jQuery, AngularJS, and Node.js?"
2. "Are they new languages?
3. "What does 'framework/library' mean?"

Question 1 is covered by [What is Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884724/what-is-node-js), [What does AngularJS do better than jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414012/what-does-angularjs-do-better-than-jquery), [What is the difference between JavaScript and jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283098/what-is-the-difference-between-javascript-and-jquery), among others.

Your third question is covered by [What is the difference between a framework and a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148747/what-is-the-difference-between-a-framework-and-a-library), [What is the difference between a JavaScript framework and a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576018/what-is-the-difference-between-a-javascript-framework-and-a-library), etc.

As you can see, there are many other questions that cover parts of yours. That's why broad questions with many sub-questions don't work well in our format: parts of your questions were duplicates of others, but since a question can only be voted as a duplicate of one other, it's impossible to give you all these links.

Note that all the duplicates I've linked above **are also closed**, because they also end up asking broad questions. "What is _____?" would be best answered by checking documentation, Wikipedia etc, and using that to ask a specific question on what you don't understand.

There's a general issue with [comparison questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/) anyway, and I'll quote the relevant section:

> I honestly feel a lot of the “this v. that” questions would be better expressed as examinations of the underlying concepts without all the mock conflict. But if you must compare and contrast two things in a Stack Exchange question — and don’t want your question to get instantly closed as Not Constructive — try to keep Gorilla vs. Shark in mind.

Regardless, you have many good answers to your question, so no cause to worry too much; if you need any additional help with that, you can ask a *more specific question*. If you follow these tips, your future questions will be more likely to lead to a productive Q&A, so I wish you good luck with that.

Answer (score 6):

> I think my question was great, but it was closed as too broad by 3 people. Why?

Because it's Too Broad.

> I think it was a great question, and it was no broad at all.

The question is *unquestionably* Too Broad.  You couldn't even fit a complete answer to that question into an entire book, let alone an SO answer.

Comment: There was a perfect answer for this, and I accepted that one. Obviously all questions will not be a simple "calculate this, tell me about this" type question, some will involve some background information. I didn't ask for specific indepth details, and just the basics really

Comment: @KSplitX You got answers that were woefully incomplete and came nowhere *near* actually answering the question that you asked.  You should have asked a different question that didn't require any more information than what you got if that's what you wanted to get as an answer, rather than asking a question that would require multiple books to answer and simply expecting people to not actually answer it.